# realmList.deleteAllFromRealm not working

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I have parent realm object like this:

```
public class Parentdb extends RealmObject {
     @PrimaryKey
     public long id;

     RealmList<Child> childs;
}
```

and I want to remove all child's from parent for that I use this code:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
parentdb.childs.deleteAllFromRealm();
realm.commitTransaction();

Child child=realm.where(Child.class).findFirst();
```

after run this code child must be null right?
but it's not!!!
am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well you probably have more than one `parentDb` in the database, and you're selecting some other child....

Comment: realm takes a lazy approach in retreiving data, so use getChilds() instead of .childs

Answer (score 1):

```
realm.beginTransaction();
parentdb = realm.where(Parentdb.class).equalTo("id", 1L).findFirst();
parentdb.childs.deleteAllFromRealm();
realm.commitTransaction();

parentdb = realm.where(Parentdb.class).equalTo("id", 1L).findFirst();
assertThat(parentdb.childs.size()).isEqualTo(0); // should be true
```

Basically you have more children in the database than just what belongs to that single `parentDb` object.